# Typing useReducer as a context value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, react-context

I want to pass useReducer as a value in StateContext.Provider. When trying to consume `useReducer` using useContext(StateContext), I get the following error:

> Type '[initialStateType, Dispatch] | null' is not an array type

I found a workaround:

`export const StateContext =  createContext([] as unknown as [initialStateType, Dispatch<Action>]);`

However, I’m not sure this type assertion is the best approach. What is the best way to type `useReducer` as a context value?

Here is the relevant code:

```
stateProvider.tsx

export const StateContext =  createContext< [initialStateType, Dispatch<Action>] | null>(null);


export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }: StateProviderProps) => {
return (
<StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
{children}
</StateContext.Provider>
)
}

Product.tsx

export const Product = ({id,title,image,price, rating}: ProductProps) => {

    const [state,dispatch] = useContext(StateContext); // error: Type '[initialStateType, Dispatch<Action>] | null' is not an array type.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an `interface` defining the state and an object containing its initial value:

```
interface AppState {

}

const initialState: AppState = {

}

export const StateContext = createContext<AppState>(initialState);

export const StateProvider = ({
  reducer,
  initialState,
  children,
}: StateProviderProps) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    // Define helper methods that will `dispatch` the various events

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{
        ...state
    }}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```